# How to add GroupByRow Double Click event handler for Outlook Group By in Infragistics Win Grid

Tags: infragistics, ultrawingrid, wingrid

I need to handle the double click event of a GroupByRow description and cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the group header row?  If so, handle the grid's DoubleClickRow event, and in your event handler test `e.Row.IsGroupByRow`.  This property will be true for the group headers.